# Sign-in Android application using Volley

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, android-volley

I want to create a sign in application using web service
the concept is to post this json object.

```
{ 
   "username" : "admin",
   "rememberMe" : true,
   "password" : "admin"
}
```

The web service give you a id_token if the user really exist
the web service is already exist. I try to use Volley library for Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("username", "admin");
params.put("rememberMe", "true");
params.put("password", "password");

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);

String url = "YOUR_URL_HERE";

JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        //TODO: handle success
        Log.e("!_@@_SUCCESS::>",response);
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
        //TODO: handle failure
        Log.e("!_@@_Error::>",error);
    }
});

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

Comment: I try it but I have two errors
01-24 14:56:50.671 31491-31491/com.nizar.abdelhedi E/!_@@_Error::>: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
01-24 14:56:50.671 31491-32520/com.nizar.abdelhedi E/Volley: [39092] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://192.168.100.28:8080/api/authenticate

Comment: you have created Local web service ?

Comment: I just set the wrong password the code is right

Comment: congratulation you solved your issue.. have a good coding .